# Как в qml вывести строку с параметром?

Tags: qt, qml

Выводится строка типа:

```
 text.text = qsTr ("Version: ") + controler.getMaximumVersion()
```

как сделать чтобы переменная шла параметром в строке (соответствено была доступна для перевода)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое это сделать так:

```
text.text = qsTr("Version: %1").arg(controler.getMaximumVersion())
```

Но если это число, при выводе которого нужно учитывать региональные стандарты, тогда синтаксис будет несколько иным. Вообще, рекомендую ознакомится с [Internationalization and Localization with Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html)